# Oculus SDK 1.3 plugin support

Tags: oculus, minko

any chances of an update to the Oculus plugin to support the latest 1.3 SDK ? Also is there basic documentation on how to write a plugin - whats premake.lua etc? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> any chances of an update to the Oculus plugin to support the latest 1.3 SDK ?

It should be fairly easy to do so using the existing source of the "vr" plugin:

https://github.com/aerys/minko/tree/master/plugin/vr

PR welcome!

> whats premake.lua etc? Thanks.

You should read the premake documentation: https://premake.github.io/
There are tons of premake examples in the documentation, including one for the oculus SDK plugin.